# Notebook too large with image sfgui

Tags: c++, sfml

I've tried to find an answer for that a few times, spent many hours on it, but I'm so stuck, and I know it's a very basic question '-' But still, I'm stuck.

So, the problem is, for my interface with SFGUI, I created a notebook, so it's working fine, the notebook is showing, it's on the right place, ...

BUT there's one thing I can't do on my own. I'm adding one image per page, it's still working fine, my images are loading, showing ...
But when I run the whole thing, I realize something. If the image is large, it will take more than 100% of the space. And to be honest, I only want 20% of the space to be used. I tried to use many things, as `SetRequisition`, on both the notebook and the image. It still doesn't work, it stays too large. So I don't know where to go, how to resize the notebook.

Here's the code, and sorry for the comments, I currently tried things, didn't take time to comment it. I'll do it very soon, because it's starting to become too much for my little brain ;-;

```
#include "Editor.h"

#include <string>

void Editor::Run() {
    sf::RenderWindow render_window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Map Editor");
    m_window = sfg::Window::Create(sfg::Window::Style::NO_STYLE);

    Init();
    render_window.resetGLStates();

    while(render_window.isOpen()) {

        while (render_window.pollEvent(m_event)) {
            m_desktop.HandleEvent(m_event);

            if (m_event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                render_window.close();
            }
        }

        m_desktop.Update(m_clock.restart().asSeconds());

        render_window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        m_sfgui.Display(render_window);
        render_window.display();
    }
}

void Editor::Init() {
    InitBoxes();

    CreateButton(&Editor::CreateFile, "res/newFile.png");
    CreateButton(&Editor::OpenFile, "res/openFile.png");

    auto updateTileButton = sfg::Button::Create("Update Tiles");
    updateTileButton->GetSignal(sfg::Button::OnLeftClick).Connect( std::bind(&Editor::UpdateTilesets, this) );
    m_tilesBox->Pack(updateTileButton, false, false);

    m_mapPreview = sfg::Canvas::Create();

    UpdateTilesets();
    m_tilesBox->Pack(m_tilesList, false, false);

    m_editBox->Pack(m_tilesBox, false, false);
    m_editBox->Pack(m_mapPreview, false, false);

    m_generalBox->Pack(m_toolsBox);
    m_generalBox->Pack(m_editBox, false, false);

    m_window->Add(m_generalBox);
    m_desktop.Add(m_window);
}

void Editor::InitBoxes() {
    m_generalBox = sfg::Box::Create(sfg::Box::Orientation::VERTICAL, 15.f);
    m_toolsBox = sfg::Box::Create(sfg::Box::Orientation::HORIZONTAL, 10.f);
    m_editBox = sfg::Box::Create(sfg::Box::Orientation::HORIZONTAL);
    m_tilesBox = sfg::Box::Create(sfg::Box::Orientation::VERTICAL);
}

void Editor::UpdateTilesets() {
    m_tilesList = sfg::Notebook::Create();
    m_tilesList->SetScrollable(true);

    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        sf::Image tileset;
        if (!tileset.loadFromFile("res/tileset" + std::to_string(i) + ".png")) {
            return;
        }
        m_tilesList->AppendPage(sfg::Image::Create(tileset), sfg::Label::Create("Tile "+std::to_string(i)));
        i++;
    }
}

bool Editor::CreateFile() {
    /** @return false if an error occurred, true otherwise. */

    return true;
}

bool Editor::OpenFile() {
    /** @return false if an error occurred, true otherwise. */

    return true;
}
```

And the Editor.h

```
#ifndef EDITOR_H
#define EDITOR_H

#include <SFGUI/SFGUI.hpp>
#include <SFGUI/Widgets.hpp>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


class Editor {
    public:
        template<typename Func>
        void CreateButton(Func&& func, std::string imagePath) {
            auto button = sfg::Button::Create();
            sf::Image newFileImage; newFileImage.loadFromFile(imagePath);
            button->SetImage(sfg::Image::Create(newFileImage));

            button->GetSignal(sfg::Button::OnLeftClick).Connect( std::bind(func, this) );
            m_toolsBox->Pack(button, false, true);
        }

        /** @brief Starts the program, initializes Window. */
        void Run();

        /** @brief Initializes widgets, sets the interface. */
        void Init();

        /** @brief Initializes boxes. */
        void InitBoxes();


        /** @brief Updates and loads the tilesets available. */
        void UpdateTilesets();

        /** @brief Creates a new map. */
        bool CreateFile();

        /** @brief Opens an existing map. */
        bool OpenFile();

    protected:
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_generalBox;
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_toolsBox;
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_editBox;
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_tilesBox;
        sfg::Notebook::Ptr m_tilesList;
        sfg::Canvas::Ptr m_mapPreview;
        sfg::Window::Ptr m_window;
        sfg::Desktop m_desktop;

    private:
        sfg::SFGUI m_sfgui;
        sf::Event m_event;
        sf::Clock m_clock;
};

#endif // EDITOR_H
```

EDIT : After some researches on the SFGUI forum, I found that it was impossible to set a size under the minimum set by SFGUI, even with SetRequisition. So I understand that resizing the Notebook will not be possible unless my image is smaller, right ?

Well, I guess the only way to do it is to show only a part of the Image, and change that part using scrolling bars in the Notebook page, is it the right way to do it ?

Comment: Off topic: Comments are nice, but code that explains itself should be your goal. Save the comments for usage documentation and when you can't make the code explain itself.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I try to set documentation (as you can see in .h), but I guess I'm doing it wrong ^^'